# Debian Dual Boot installation GRUB not showing

Tags: debian, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I am trying to install *debian-live-8.4.0-amd64-cinnamon-desktop.iso*  (available from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/8.4.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/)) to my PC with windows 10 OS.

**I did following steps:**

- I put it on USB
- Booted from USB
- I had ~105GB of free space which was automatically
  divided between root (/) (~100GB), swap (~5GB) and BIOSBOOT(1MB).
- I ran Debian installation.
- GRUB2 (It is v2 I think) installation comes up, and it says something
  about it did not find any other OS and if I want to install grub to
  the MBR. I select **yes** and then I select **SSD with windows installation**
  (where Debian was installed as well) **/dev/sdb** and GRUB seems to be
  installed.

But after reboot, GRUB is not showing. If I go into bios, there is no BIOS boot point for grub, just Windows Boot Manager/DVD-ROM/My nework card/(and USB/UEFI USB in case USB is connected...)

After installation SSD is divided in following order:

- Recovery Partition (~450MB)
- EFI System Partition (~100MB)
- C: NTFS (~366GB)
- BIOSBOOT (~1MB)
- Ext4 (~94.59GB)
- Swap (~4,04GB)

I also had my HDD (/dev/sda) and USB (/dev/sdc) connected during installation
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your firmware set to boot in BIOS compatibility mode? Your description makes me suspect it's not, in which case GRUB should not be installed to the MBR.

Comment: I think it is, but I am not sure. What I know is - I have BIOS in my laptop (Asus G75VW). When I plugin USB with debian I have two boot points available <USBNAME> and UEFI <USBNAME>. I always boot from <USBNAME> option. I tried from UEFI too but it does not seem to work (If I have UEFI <USBNAME> and Windows Boot Manager afterwards, Windows starts loading). I have no UEFI/BIOS comp. mode option in my BIOS.

Comment: Okay its looks like it is in UEFI. I am following this tutorial https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall . Using mentioned tutorial I was able to boot into my debian and  command [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" returned "EFI boot on HDD". So for I cannot find partition with boot folder though.

Comment: I guess it is on the 94 gig Ext4 partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, partially thanks to @Johan Meyreen I think I now understand what happened and I fixed it.

Debian Jessie installation does not support UEFI boot option, and since my PC ran on UEFI, grub boot option was simply not installed.

I booted into Debian via [rEFInd Boot Manager tool](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and then followed [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=81120) simple guide to install grub into EFI partition.

Now debian boot option is available in bios and grub seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a top result for Windows 10/Debian dual boot issues.
For dual-booting Windows 10/Debian 10 (Buster), I had the same issue. The solution that worked for me was:

1. In Windows, open a Command Prompt (I used Administrator)
2. Enter:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi
   ```

After restarting, GRUB showed up as expected.

Comment: Did not work for me. Additionally broke the windows boot manager. I needed to put installation usb and need to to set bootmgr path to default bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi