# Dual boot doesn't load Debian/GRUB anymore only windows

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have a Dell Notebook with Windows 10 installed. I installed debian about 4 months ago making it a **dual boot option**. Have been using debian daily, everyday it shows me the GRUB and **auto loads into debian**. Yesterday decided to go into windows, just selected windows in GRUB, now I can't go back into debian.

I shutdown/restart and always loads windows. It doesn't even show me the GRUB.
The boot loader first option is debian and the second windows boot manager, nonetheless it doesn't load debian.

**Already tried:**

- Manually choosing the debian option in boot loader (f12)
- Disabled secure boot.
- Tried windows recovery options > advanced restart
- Was about to remove windows boot loader from boot options but BIOS didn't allowed me to.

What else can I do?

**EDIT:**
Well, I decided to follow [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570413) instructions and now nothing boots anymore, neither debian or windows... 
This is the command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi
```

**EDIT 2:**
As requested this is the output of `sudo parted --list`

```
user@debian:~$ sudo parted --list
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVX-75J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      525MB   567MB   41.9MB  fat32           Basic data partition          hidden
 3      567MB   701MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      701MB   1488MB  786MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 5      1488MB  834GB   833GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 8      834GB   846GB   12.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
 9      846GB   991GB   145GB   ext4
 6      991GB   992GB   979MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 7      992GB   1000GB  7892MB  ntfs            Microsoft recovery partition  hidden, diag


Model: Sony Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.1GB  16.1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Comment: can you boot a live sesssion and show `sudo parted --list` please.

Comment: @nobody just edited the question with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to redo the GRUB Installation process (if at least grub seems to load, you can skip step 3):

1. boot from a linux live iso (e.g. debian live iso)
2. mount your efi system partition:
   `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
3. grub needs devices: `mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
4. chroot into your debian system: `chroot /mnt`
5. reinstall grub entry in firmware boot manager: 
   `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt`
6. let grub detect the installed operating systems (if I remember right grub should output the detected operating systems):
   `grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/grub/grub.cfg`

https://fosswire.com/post/2009/05/restoring-overwritten-grub/

Comment: Since my first edit my **windows also stopped working**. I imagine reinstalling the GRUB won't change anything for windows, however, just to be sure, it also won't remove/corrupt any windows files/boot data right?

Comment: Grub will of course change boot data, but that is actually what we want, if we have a dual boot setup, because we just want our Firmware to boot Grub and let Grub handle the rest (e.g booting windows or linux). But I can of course not give you a guarantee.

Comment: Very well, however the command 3 returns ```grub-install: command not found``` I'm using a Debian Live session. Btw managed to recover windows by using an ISO. However stll no debian...

Comment: Got it, I used this tutorial https://fosswire.com/post/2009/05/restoring-overwritten-grub/ and the last command didn't worked so I used your command 3. Please include this link in your answer so I can accept it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I forgot the chroot... my bad sorry.