# How do i get the GRUB screen back

Tags: linux-mint, grub, uefi

recently i installed mint, on the grub screen there was an option for something to do with U.E.F.I, out of curiosity, i booted into it, i turned my computer off, and then back on, it booted into windows without any grub screen, my next instinct was to restart, same result, is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Windows might have overwritten something on your EFI partition, or just NVRAM (boot options and boot order) - might have something to do with the recent ["boothole" secureboot vulnerability](https://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities---threats/boothole-vulnerability-exposes-secure-boot-devices-to-attack/d/d-id/1338487).

The first thing to do is get to a manual UEFI/BIOS boot selection screen for your laptop/desktop. This is usually one of the Function keys (F12, F11, F2 are common, but there's no actual standard across manufacturers). Check the manual or online documentation for your hardware.

1. While your machine is booting, repeatedly hit the "boot menu" key. If you see a boot loader, splash screen or OS starting, then you've waited too long or hit the wrong key - try again!
2. If you are lucky, in the UEFI/BIOS boot menu you'll see an option to boot to Mint, Grub or something you might recognize as associated with your Mint installation (if you don't, skip to "Boot Repair").
3. Select the option to boot to your Mint instance, but... **keep reading, you're not home free yet!**
4. Open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub` to update your grub. Depending on what got you to this state, that may be enough, but if not then you may need run something like `grub-install...` to make sure your EFI is set up correctly for dual-boot and your boot order points to Grub first.

If the above doesn't get you sorted, then you should follow [Ubuntu's documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) on this since Mint is based on Ubuntu, in this case the process to fix your grub is the same.

If all else fails, go to the Mint or Ubuntu specific forums and ask for a lifeline there.

Comment: My Windows install keeps changing the boot order every time I boot it. I had to resort to the method mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570413 (with `EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` instead of the debian variant) to make the change permanent.

Comment: Oh sure, that works as well. :) The above is a bit more general purpose, since using `bcdedit` requires that you know the specific path to your `grubx64.efi`, which varies between distros and even from newer and older versions of a distro. The method you used is much more direct though.

Comment: where is the path for mint?

Comment: hmmm... don;t know for certain. Ubuntu base for most Mint, but then I think they're moving to a Debian base, and there's already Linux Mint Debian edition which is based on (you guessed it) Debian. I would expect it's either `EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` or `EFI\debian\grubx64.efi`...

Comment: i fixed it, no need to tell me

Comment: um, ok... why don't you share how you fixed it as other people who read this might like to know...? If my answer was your solution then please select it as chosen solution, otherwise answer it yourself, post the solution you used and then you'll be helping other people who encounter the problem, just as I helped you...